# Update (a function) post's featured image as soon as $image_url changes

Tags: plugins, php, functions, post-thumbnails, automatic-updates

everyone! I've been making a wordpress plugin which gets seperate instagram photos and then puts them in shortcodes. Though, the shortcodes display images not saved in WP images folder, but directly from instagram. It makes the server loading times drastically increase.

So I searched WP dev forums and found this function which sets the featured image for the specified post.

```
function Generate_Featured_Image( $image_url, $post_id  ){
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = basename($image_url);
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))     $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else                                    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $res2= set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

What am I missing is the fact that the photos I take get updated shortly and the featured image doesn't change after that. Would there be any way to update the featured image as soon as a new instagram photo gets uploaded? Or just every hour or so. 
Thanks a bunch, guys!

Comment: The way you're downloading and saving the data to the media library is rather fragile and longwinded, is there a specific reason you didn't use `media_sideload_iamge( $url, $post_id );` ?

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for the reference to media_sideload_image`function.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get URL of the image from Instagram and you know `id` of the post, you can use use the function from your question. You have to modify the code for the only `if` statement in it:

```
if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir[ 'path' ] ) ) {
    $file = $upload_dir[ 'path' ] . '/' . $filename;
} else {
    $file = $upload_dir[ 'basedir' ] . '/' . $filename;
}
```

This function will upload the image to the media library and set it as a featured image for your post. Tested!

Or, based on suggestion by @TomJNowell from his comment, use this code:

```
$attach_id = media_sideload_image( $image_url, $post_id, 'Instagram image', 'id' );
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```